# What's the best way of modifying event handler in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to call this method in the dispatch function "Platform.performMicrotaskCheckpoint()".

For eg.

```
dispatch: function( event ) {
    Platform.performMicrotaskCheckpoint();
  //rest of the code goes here  
}
```

What is the best way of doing it instead of making changes in jquery library ?
How to override jquery event handlers ?

Comment: `I have to call this method in the dispatch function` Could you explain why? That's said, maybe you could use following snippet (pasted in jsFiddle): http://jsfiddle.net/s3s6mtt0/

Comment: Actually I am using observe.js in my code and it has compatibility issue on IE and Mozilla Firefox. Thanks it worked.